# Does the ending dialogue change if I never sell any shards?

Tags: bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night

During my fight against the final boss...

> Dominique mentioned being thankful for the shards I sold her during the game.

To quote:

> *I have you and Johannes to thank for teaching me the Alchemists’ lore and how to control the shards.
>
>  Shards, I might add, which you gave to me of your own will. Your sacrifice has become my strength.*

What happens if you beat the game without selling any shards? Does this dialogue change at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the dialogue changes slightly. I looked up videos of the final boss and found one where:

> Dominique skipped the line about [giving up shards of your own free will](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89uPizgHec0&t=40s).

Aside from this, the rest of the dialogue was identical.

Answer (score 5):

> Does this dialogue change at all?

> No, it doesn't.
>  I sold zero shards on my first playthrough and she still talked as if I had sold her shards.

Comment: [Looking at videos online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89uPizgHec0&t=40s), it seems the line about about giving up shards doesn't always play.